# How to set Git Bash directory to home?

Tags: bash, git-bash, msys

when I start up git bash I get the following location as my startup location:

```
[Me]@[Me] MINGW64 /
$ dir
bin  cmd  dev  etc  git-bash.exe  git-cmd.exe  LICENSE.txt  mingw64  proc 
ReleaseNotes.html  tmp  unins000.dat  unins000.exe  usr
```

How can I change it so that I am in my documents folder on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the Windows environment variable %HOME% to your Document folder, a simple cd will get you there.

```
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%\Documents
git bash
cd
```

With [git version 2.8.3.windows.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.8.3.windows.1), typing `git bash` in any folder opens a git bash in that folder.
Then type `cd` and you are at `$HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

As in all versions of bash, this is the default behavior of `cd` if given no arguments, or the explicitly-specified behavior of `cd ~` or `cd "$HOME"`:

```
$ pwd
/
$ cd
$ pwd
/c/Users/Charles Duffy
```

Similarly, `cd ~/Documents` will move to the `Documents` subdirectory of same.

Answer (score 0):

There are side effects of setting HOME. For example emacs gets a new home, which is not in the roaming profile.

So, as an alternative, edit .bash_profile, add this at the end: `cd ~` .